# My Windows 7 Install Has Lost Its Default "double click to open file" Behavior

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, double-click

Something in my Win7 Pro SP1 installation has changed recently. It used to be that when you mouse over a file name in Windows Explorer nothing happened. Single click selected, double click opened. Now, the behavior is that hovering over a file name selects it, and a single click opens it. One result of this is that file previews are no longer visible in the right-hand pane, since they were activated on the single click.
I have looked at the setting in "Tools\Folder Options\General" and **the "Double click..." radio button is active and "single click to open..." is grayed out**. There is something fishy about that. I've tried the "reset to defaults" button there with no effect. I've also tried to delete a registry key in ClassicShell settings under:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer  -as mentioned here http://tinyurl.com/ocgcfpp  but that didn't work either. This feature only works in system windows like Explorer or the Desktop, not in browser windows or in other applications, so I believe it is a Windows setting issue. Any help would be appreciated--Thanks.